# Shell script issue with filenames containing spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, filenames

I understand that one technique for dealing with spaces in filenames is to enclose the file name with single quotes: "'".

Why is it that the following code called, "echo.sh" works on a directory containing filenames with spaces, but the program "ls.sh" does Not work, where the only difference is 'echo' replaced with 'ls'?

echo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *
do
echo "'$f'"
done
```

**Produces**:
    'a b c' 
    'd e f' 
    'echo.sh' 
    'ls.sh'

But, "ls.sh" fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *
do
ls "'$f'"
done
```

**Produces**:
    ls: cannot access 'a b c': No such file or directory 
    ls: cannot access 'd e f': No such file or directory 
    ls: cannot access 'echo.sh': No such file or directory 
    ls: cannot access 'ls.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: `ls` is looking for the names encased with single quotes and does not find them. e.g The file 'a b c' does not exist.

Comment: Then why does:   ls 'a b c' work fine as a stand alone command?

Comment: The file 'a b c' does exist. so ls 'a b c' works. But the file ''a b c'' does not exist.

Comment: <a b c> exists,   <'a b c'> does not exist. Not easy to type something about this quoting that is clear!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you're actually adding redundant "'" (which your echo invocation shows)

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *
do
ls "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

change the following line from

```
ls "'$f'"
```

into

```
ls "$f"
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a closer look at the output of your echo.sh script you might notice the result is probably not quite the one you expected as every line printed is surrounded by `'` characters like:

```
'file-1'
'file-2'
```

and so on.

Files with that names really don't exist on your system. Using them with `ls` ls will try to look up a file named `'file-1'` instead of `file-1` and a file with such a name just doesn't exist.

In your example you just added one pair of `'`s too much. A single pair of double quotes`"` is enough to take care of spaces that might contained in the file names:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *
do
  ls "$f"
done
```

Will work pretty fine even with file names containing spaces. The problem you are trying to avoid would only arise if you didn't use the double quotes around `$f` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *
do
  ls $f # you might get into trouble here
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this ? =)

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *; do
    printf -- '%s\n' "$f"
done
```