# deal with filename with space in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511006/shell-script-issue-with-filenames-containing-spaces) here,but still got wrong.
In my folder,I only want to deal with `*.gz` file,`Windows 10.tar.gz` got space in filename.

Assume the folder contain:

`Windows 10.tar.gz  Windows7.tar.gz otherfile`

Here is my shell scripts,I tried everything to quote with "",still can't got what I want.
crypt_import_xml.sh

```
#/bin/sh

rule_dir=/root/demo/rule
function crypt_import_xml()
{
    rule=$1
    # list the file in absoulte path
    for file in `ls ${rule}/*.gz`; do
        echo "${file}"
        #tar -xf *.gz

        #mv a b.xml to ab.xml

    done
}

crypt_import_xml ${rule_dir}
```

Here is what I got:

```
root@localhost.localdomain:[/root/demo]./crypt_import_xml.sh 
/root/demo/rule/Windows
10.tar.gz
/root/demo/rule/Windows7.tar.gz
```

After tar xf the *.gz file,the xml filename still contain space.It is a nightmare for me to deal with filename contain spaces.

Comment: Can you use: `for file in "${rule}"/*.gz; do
        echo "${file}"
        #tar -xf *.gz

        #mv a b.xml to ab.xml

    done` and let me know if it works? You do not need the `ls` command in the first place

Comment: @Allan still got the same result with ls command.

Comment: There should not be any `ls` command

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: (OT: @J.Doe Your code has a few issues (broken shebang, `function` is a bashism, etc), may I recommend https://www.shellcheck.net ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ls` in `for` loop.

```
$ ls directory 
file.txt  'file with more spaces.txt'  'file with spaces.txt'
```

Using `ls`:

```
$ for file in `ls ./directory`; do echo "$file"; done
file.txt
file
with
more
spaces.txt
file
with
spaces.txt
```

Using file globbing:

```
$ for file in ./directory/*; do echo "$file"; done 
./directory/file.txt
./directory/file with more spaces.txt
./directory/file with spaces.txt
```

So:

```
for file in "$rule"/*.gz; do
    echo "$file"
    #tar -xf *.gz

    #mv a b.xml to ab.xml
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call that `ls` command in the for loop, the file globbing will take place in your shell, without running this additional command:

```
XXX-macbookpro:testDir XXX$ ls -ltra
total 0
drwx------+ 123 XXX  XXX  3936 Feb 22 17:15 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 XXX  XXX     0 Feb 22 17:15 abc 123
drwxr-xr-x    3 XXX  XXX    96 Feb 22 17:15 .
XXX-macbookpro:testDir XXX$ rule=.
XXX-macbookpro:testDir XXX$ for f in "${rule}"/*; do echo "$f"; done
./abc 123
```

In your case you can change the `"${rule}"/*` into:

```
"${rule}"/*.gz;
```

Comment: can not work,If don't change directory,still got wrong.